# Parallel Scans in Google BigTable provide speedup?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to optimize the scan time of a query. The query is a simple range query with no filters.  When I run the query it usually takes about 10 seconds to perform the scan on unsalted time series data (about 1.8 million rows each containing 32 byte values and 40 byte keys).

Should I expect a speedup if I salt the data then run the scans in parallel?

For example, I could append each row with a number 0,1,2,3,4,5 randomly. Then I could have a thread pool of size 6 to perform 6 separate scans in parallel. When I currently do this, I am not seeing any speedup whatsoever, which leads be to believe that maybe something is going on behind the scenes that would nullify any benefit of parallel scans.

There is very little documentation on this, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Usually, parallelization helps.  There is likely something else going on.  How is your Scan set up (i.e. what kind of filters are you setting)?

Answer (score 0):

After checking my assumptions, I realized that the VM I was using only had two VCPUs. I increased that to SALT_RANGE and got the expected speedup. So basically, make sure that the number of CPUs can handle the load.  Below is the abbreviated Java code (I am dealing with Maps for my data) for running the scan in parallel.

```
ForkJoinPool myPool = new ForkJoinPool(Config.SALT_RANGE);

results = myPool.submit(() -> 
        IntStream.range(0,Config.SALT_RANGE).parallel().mapToObj(salt -> {
                    Scan scan = buildMyScan();
                    Table t = agent.getTableMain();
                    out = performScan(scan);
                    return  out;
                }).map(Map::entrySet).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> merger(a, b), TreeMap::new)))
            .get();
```